# How to quit using the Alt+F4 key?

Tags: c#, wpf

I write a WPF application with C#. How to quit using the Alt + F4 key?

This is my code that does not work:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftAlt && e.Key == Key.F4)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

[image: xmls]

Comment: `Alt` + `F4` will kill any process, why do you want to handle it yourself? Also, `e.Key` can only be one value at a time, you need to remember whether `alt` was pressed before `f4`

Comment: As noted in the previous comment, assuming you don't do anything special in your program, Alt+F4 already closes the window and the process. You shouldn't need code like what you've posted. So if you're having trouble, you need to ask a question in which you include a good [mcve] showing what you did to break the standard Alt+F4 behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect multiple keys down onkeydown event in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013087/how-to-detect-multiple-keys-down-onkeydown-event-in-wpf)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this instead

```
if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
   && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.F4) ) { 
    // do something other than exit
}
```

Comment: Though perhaps true, encouraging people to handle Alt-F4 explicitly should be considered frowned-upon as Windows will do it for you

Comment: Sometimes you don't want a user to be able to exit the code.  There are valid or even normal situations, that actually require it.

Comment: _"[Closing can be handled to detect when a window is being closed (for example, when Close is called). Furthermore, **Closing can be used to prevent a window from closing**. To **prevent** a window from **closing**, you can **set the Cancel property** of the CancelEventArgs argument to true.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)"_